# How would you make EF calls generic?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

I have this sample code (.NET Core 2.2):

```
private void IterateSave(List<TokenMaster> items, int min, int max)
{
    int skip = min;
    int take = max / 5;
    while (skip <= max)
    {
        try
        {
            var subItems = items.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
            _db.TokenMasters.AddRange(subItems); // <---
            _db.SaveChanges();
            skip += take;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Error saving this data batch! {RecordCount}", take);
            IterateSave(items, skip, take);
        }
    }
}

private void IterateSave(List<Attributes> items, int min, int max)
{
    int skip = min;
    int take = max / 5;
    while (skip <= max)
    {
        try
        {
            var subItems = items.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
            _db.Attributes.AddRange(subItems); // <---
            _db.SaveChanges();
            skip += take;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Error saving this data batch! {RecordCount}", take);
            IterateSave(items, skip, take);
        }
    }
}
```

How would you turn this into a single generic call?  I am struggling with the `DbSet` and `Model` being required.

Comment: EF calls already *are* generic. All calls in these methods are generic already, except the calls to the DbSet<T> properties `Attributes` and `TokenMasters`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? Why not add all items in a single go? Or use SqlBulkCopy to insert rows in bulk with minimal logging?

Comment: Getting large datasets from a 3rd party REST service, poorly defined, data sizes are changing causing inserts to fail.  This will, at a cost, allow me to save the majority of data when that happens.  Doing it in one pass is a all/none only.

Comment: You can specify batch sizes in SqlBulkCopy too. A better option would be to store incoming data in a staging table and then move it to the target table. Right now, for `SaveChanges` to fail means that the *entities* can accept invalid data (why?) or that the EF context is out of sync with the database. You should validate the entities before trying to save them.

Comment: All good advice but does not fit the problem space I find myself in.  Believe me, I've been doing imports for nearly 30 years.  The endpoints I find myself hitting do NOT have definitions (field 1 : string 50 chars) and can change without notice.  This is a serious hit to perf to capture those records that are outside the presumed data boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not as simple as:

```
private void IterateSave<T>(List<T> items, int min, int max) where T : class
{
    int skip = min;
    int take = max / 5;
    while (skip <= max)
    {
        try
        {
            var subItems = items.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
            _db.Set<T>().AddRange(subItems);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            skip += take;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Error saving this data batch! {RecordCount}", take);
            IterateSave(items, skip, take);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are mostly right.  Need to tweak the method definition to: `private void IterateSave<T>(List<T> items, int min, int max) where T : class`.  Thank you!